# Python Argparse Flags dependent on Task

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

So I have a program I'm writing using argparse in python 3.5. Now there's an issue I'm running into now, where I want to appoint the flags to the tasks.

```
wasp init -m
```

or

```
wasp tag -g
```

But I want `-g` to not work for `init`, and vice versa
I currently only have init functionality working, but I don't want to add the `-g` flag until I know how to handle `tag`

Source is here:

```
description = 'Generate and create basic resources for a modern web app. Initialize a project with a manifest, package, and tags versions effectively'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description)
parser.add_argument('task', metavar='task', type=str, help='A task to perform. Options : init, update, tag')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--manifest', action='store_true', help='Generate a manifest.json for your project')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--package', action='store_true', help='Generate a package.json for your project')
```

Comment: I dont see `-g` option, nor do i see init. Can you please be more accurate in asking the question?

Comment: Check out `add_subparsers`